# Cómo insertar un button reset para limpiar mi table?

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TIC TAC TOE</h1>
  <table class="board board-js">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>  
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset">
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi código de JavaScript:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var board=document.querySelector('.board-js');

board.addEventListener('click',addX);

};
var centinel=false;

function addX(event){
    if(centinel)
        event.target.textContent='X';
    else
        event.target.textContent='O';
        centinel=!centinel;
}

board.addEventListener('click', reset);

function reset() {
    document.getElementById("board-js").reset();
}
```

Comment: Podrías compartir un poco de tu HTML? Creo que ayudará a que la gente te respondiera más rápido. Saludos.

Comment: @DIANAHUAMANCHAY edita la pregunta (dándole al enlace de [edit] en la parte inferior izquierda de la pregunta), para añadir el código en la publicación y no como comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que entiendo es que quieres borrar los datos de la tabla, si es así podrías hacer algo como esto:

```js
function reset(){
    var table = document.getElementById('board-js');

    table.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<h1>TIC TAC TOE</h1>
<table class="board board-js" id="board-js">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
            <td>Item 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 7</td>
            <td>Item 8</td>
            <td>Item 9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>  
<input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="Reset" id="reset">
```

Si lo que quieres es simplemente borrar el contenido de los `<td>` pero mantener la estructura podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
function reset(){
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for(var i = 0; i < td.length; i++){
        td[i].innerHTML = ''
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>TIC TAC TOE</h1>
<table class="board board-js" id="board-js">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
            <td>Item 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 7</td>
            <td>Item 8</td>
            <td>Item 9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>  
<input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="Reset" id="reset">
```

Estoy pendiente por si requieres algo más.

Comment: Interesante sería saber que pasaría si existiera un `thead` en la tabla :)

Comment: @Dev.Joel pero en su estructura no lo tiene, y si lo hubiera realizaría exactamente lo mismo pero con el tbody :D

Comment: se borra toda la tabla y solo quisiera limpiar el texto  y mantener la tabla

Comment: @DIANAHUAMANCHAY siendo así dame unos minutos y te hago el otro ejemplo con tu requerimiento

Comment: @DIANAHUAMANCHAY ya he editado la respuesta con otro ejemplo teniendo en cuenta su requerimiento, saludos !

Comment: gracias..me sirvio de mucho